# Autofac property injection for manually instantiated objects

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }
}
```

`IDependency` and `Test` are registered in my Autofac builder. My `IDependency` resolution works fine, but what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to return new instances of `Test` in the code (e.g. `return new Test();`) and have it's `IDependency` properties prepopulated by Autofac.

What I've tried in my container:

```
builder.Register(x => new Test {
    x.Resolve<IDependency>()
});
```

However, everytime I `new Test()` in the code, it's `IDependency` property is `null`. Is that possible?

(*for reference, my train of thought leading to this attempt was that I initially did constructor injection for `Test` but then realized that in some cases I need to manually construct `new Test()` instances in the code, and couldn't figure out what to put to satisfy the constructor signature `public Test(IDependency dependency)` and still have Autofac resolve that dependency*)

Comment: You should use Autofac to resolve dependencies, when you're using `new` keyword it's nothing but constructor of the real implementation and not the abstraction. I would suggest define `ITest` kind of interface and register it alongside with IDependency.

Comment: Also if you want to manually construct the objects - you should manually inject theses objects. I think autofac allows that, you may take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876393/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-objects-which-require-parameters-using-autofac

Comment: It appears your code snippet may have a typo - the `x.Resolve<IDependency>()` isn't being assigned to any property.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought - are you saying you need some mechanism to construct a new instance of the `Test` object (with it's dependencies injected) programatically in your code?

There's a handy feature built into Autofac to obtain factory for a registered type. I'd suggest you switch back to constructor injection:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(IDependency dependency)
    {
        Dependency = dependency;
    }

    public IDependency Dependency { get; }
}
```

and then register the types with Autofac as:

```
cb.ResisterType<MyDependency>().As<IDependency>();    
cb.RegisterType<Test>();
```

Then all you need to do wherever you're wanting to manually construct a new instance of Test() is request a `Func<Test>` in your constructor. Autofac will generate a factory allowing you to instansiate a Test class whenever you like ... but without tight coupling to the Autofac library:

```
public class SomeAppLogic
{
    public SomeAppLogic(Func<Test> testFactory)
    {
        // Some app logic
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Invoke the testFactory to obtain a new instance 
            // of a Test class from the IoC container
            Test newTestInstance = testFactory.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Autofac refers to this as 'Dynamic Instantiation', which is covered here:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b

Comment: Totally correct, though I might add you can do `lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(theObject)` and Autofac will inject the properties on a previously constructed object.